# how do i use css sprites

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a sprite that I want to use defining a class to and not an id:

[image: sprite]

I want to use the white one to show expansion option and black one to show expanded state. For non expanded state I have a class `sprite-right` and want to use `sprite-expanded` for expanded state. Can anyone guide me through this? I forgot pasting what I did...duh!

```
sprite-right
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:16px;
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:transparent no-repeat 0 0;
    background-image:url('../images/arrows.gif');
}
```

Comment: [Please describe what you've tried.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple to set up. You first need to set a class for applying the image as a background. Then add specific classes for each icon. Then in your CSS you change the background position, height and width to match the location of each icon. Here is an example:

```
.icon {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.png');
    display: block;
}

.icon.sprite-right {
    background-position: 0 0;
    height: 10px; // You can change these for each sprite
    width: 10px; // You can change these for each sprite
}
.icon.sprite-expanded {
    background-position: -10px 0; 
}
.icon.sprite-right:hover  {
    background-position: -20px 0;
}
.icon.sprite-expanded:hover {
    background-position: -30px 0;
}
```

Then, as you add new sprites you simply adjust the position until you can see the icon and then adjust the height and width until you are not clipping the image.

Answer (score 1):

There are many great tutorials out there if you do a Google search. I use this tool alot when dealing with simple sprites.

Check out this link: http://labs.engageinteractive.co.uk/nav-o-matic/

Here is a codepen I forked so I can understand sprites a little better.

http://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/lntzE

Study the code and it will start making sense to you.
Use background positioning to move your sprites to the desired class/state.

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

This post should help :  http://mindthesemicolon.com/using-css-sprites/
It explains how to create and use sprites, with a code pen example.

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link